# Move subview to different view, in a different size class

Tags: ios, autolayout, size-classes

I'm having a problem with moving subviews in different size classes, here is my problem.

I want to build two layouts for landscape and portrait (autolayout and size classes)

Here is the desired UI
[image]

In portrait I want the `red view` to be a subview of `magenta view`, while in landscape to move the `red view` to be the subview of the controllers view (the `white view`).

I can set different constraints for portrait and landscape for the `red view`, if it remains a subview to the `magenta view` and it all works fine.
But if I move it out to the `white view`, it disappears form the other orientation/size class.

Is there a way of solving this problem from Interface Builder, without duplicating the `red view`?

I'm trying to avoid to activate/deactivate constraints from code.

Link to the [project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8669046/Test.zip).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. From portrait size class set constraints. Then change size class for landscape and then drag this view out from it super view and put it to desired location.

And `uninstall` constraints of portrait class for this size class and set new required constraints for this size class.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: hi @Lion, as I said in the question, it works as long as it stays in the same view, but when I move it out, it disappears from the other orientation.

Comment: If you uninstall all the constraint of one size class then you can set totally new scenario for other size class. In landscape size class put that view out of it's superview and set proper constraints. It should work

Comment: The constraints are set for the w-Compact h-Regular, so they are uninstalled for w-Regular h-Compact. I've added the link to the test project.

Comment: So you want red view inside magenta view in portrait and out of magenta view at right top corner in landscape?.

Comment: Yes, that's the wanted behavior, inside magenta in portrait and outside in landscape.

Comment: This is not possible like you want. You can use two different red view or you have to do it programatically